# Remove strange gradient from Tab text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, material-design

When I bump the text size up in my TabBar, I start to see a gradient that is being applied automatically to my Tab instances. Screenshot:

[image]

Note the gradient on the text on the vertical axis. How is it possible to remove this? The only way I've found so far is to swap out Tab's with customised Text widgets, but then I loose the out-of-the-box Icon functionality and various other features.

Here's a boiled-down version of my code which creates the issue:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
      
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}
      
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          controller: tabController,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a different result in the display for me! Anyway, you can use 'child' instead of 'text':

```
tabs: [
   Tab(child: Text('Tab 1'),),
   Tab(child: Text('Tab 2'),),
   Tab(child: Text('Tab 3'),),
   Tab(child: Text('Tab 4'),),
],
```

**Update**

Because the size of your text is unusual and larger than the standard, and since the tab size is fixed, you can customize the tab class and change the fixed size to your desired size. change these sizes as you want:

```
final double _kTabHeight = 48.0;
final double _kTextAndIconTabHeight = 72.0;
```

and 'custom_tab.dart' class is:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTab extends StatelessWidget {

  final double _kTabHeight = 80.0;
  final double _kTextAndIconTabHeight = 72.0;

  /// Creates a material design [TabBar] tab.
  ///
  /// At least one of [text], [icon], and [child] must be non-null. The [text]
  /// and [child] arguments must not be used at the same time. The
  /// [iconMargin] is only useful when [icon] and either one of [text] or
  /// [child] is non-null.
  const CustomTab({
    Key? key,
    this.text,
    this.icon,
    this.iconMargin = const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    this.child,
  }) : assert(text != null || child != null || icon != null),
        assert(text == null || child == null),
        super(key: key);

  /// The text to display as the tab's label.
  ///
  /// Must not be used in combination with [child].
  final String? text;

  /// The widget to be used as the tab's label.
  ///
  /// Usually a [Text] widget, possibly wrapped in a [Semantics] widget.
  ///
  /// Must not be used in combination with [text].
  final Widget? child;

  /// An icon to display as the tab's label.
  final Widget? icon;

  /// The margin added around the tab's icon.
  ///
  /// Only useful when used in combination with [icon], and either one of
  /// [text] or [child] is non-null.
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry iconMargin;

  Widget _buildLabelText() {
    return child ?? Text(text!, softWrap: false, overflow: TextOverflow.fade);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterial(context));

    final double height;
    final Widget label;
    if (icon == null) {
      height = _kTabHeight;
      label = _buildLabelText();
    } else if (text == null && child == null) {
      height = _kTabHeight;
      label = icon!;
    } else {
      height = _kTextAndIconTabHeight;
      label = Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: icon,
            margin: iconMargin,
          ),
          _buildLabelText(),
        ],
      );
    }

    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      child: Center(
        child: label,
        widthFactor: 1.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(StringProperty('text', text, defaultValue: null));
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<Widget>('icon', icon, defaultValue: null));
  }
}
```

and use that like this:

```
tabs: [
   CustomTab(text: 'Tab 1'),
   CustomTab(text: 'Tab 2'),
   CustomTab(text: 'Tab 3'),
   CustomTab(text: 'Tab 4'),
],
```

I hope this useful for you :)

Comment: Yeah I’ve noticed that you can use child. Problem with this is that it seems to cut off the bottom of any text that goes over the baseline (the text “descenders”).

Comment: Copy and paste my code into a Flutter DartPad to see what I mean.

Comment: I copied your code but it had a different result with the photo!

Comment: In Flutter DartPad? Or in iOS/Android?